# Transformers architecture for machine translation

Tags: nlp

I have adapted the base transformer model, for my corpus of aligned Arabic-English sentences. As such the model has trained for 40 epochs and accuracy (SparseCategoricalAccuracy) is improving by a factor of 0.0004 for each epoch.
To achieve good results, my estimate is to attain final accuracy anywhere around 0.5 and accuracy after 40 epochs is 0.0592.

I am running the model on the tesla 2 p80 GPU. Each epoch is taking ~2690 sec.
This implies I need at least 600 epochs and training time would be 15-18 days.
Should I continue with the training or is there something wrong in the procedure as the base transformer in the research paper was trained on an ENGLISH-FRENCH corpus?

Key highlights:

1. Byte-pair(encoding) of sentences
2. Maxlen_len =100
3. batch_size= 64
4. No pre-trained embeddings were used.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Tesla K80 on aws p2.xlarge instance.
If that is the case, these gpus are very slow. You should use p3 instances on aws with V100 gpus. You will get around 6-7 times speedup. 
Checkout [this](https://avp-project.uk/blog-gpu-box-vs-cloud-for-deep-learning) for more details.

Also, if you are not using the standard model and have made some changes to model or dataset, then try to tune the hyperparameters. Simplest is to try decreasing the learning rate and see if you get better results.

Also, first try to run the standard model with standard dataset to benchmark the time taken in that case and then make your changes and proceed. See when the model starts converging in the standard case. I feel that it should give some results after 40 epochs also.